# Not able to run parameter passed methods in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testng

i am using java with selenium , maven, testng for my project. 
   for some functions , i have passed parameters through testng parameters annotations. 
   while build and executing the project through jenkins, 
    parameter passed methods are not executed through jenkins. 
    other methods are executed fine. 
          Please provide solutions. Awaiting the response

**sample code**

```
@Test(priority=1) 
    @Parameters({"drivername","driverpath","outputpath","URL"})

public void opendriver(@Optional("drivername") String drivername,@Optional("driverpath") String driverpath,@Optional("outputpath") String outputpath,@Optional("URL") String URL) 

    in the above code i have passed some parameters through  testng. while executing the code 
    through maven it is working fine. but making build in jenkins and execute the script
     it is not working. Please suggest and advise
```

Comment: And there's no output in logs? the reason why such tests were ignored. Is there a difference in run command in jenkins with that one you use locally?

Comment: in local , i am executing classes using testsuite option in Run Configuration in maven. in jenkins, i have set the classpath with Test jar of corrosponding package, created bin folder along with available classes and lib files, and testng tml